# How to submit a form using sweet alert confirm?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, sweetalert

I'm trying to submit a form after confirming it using  [sweet alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/). But, somehow my form is bypassing the sweet alert confirm (sent without confirmation).

What I am trying to do is.

- Press submit
- Show sweet alert
- IF yes is clicked = send form
- If cancel is clicked = close sweet alert

Here's my script

```
$("#btn_submit").on('click',function(e){ //also can use on submit
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit
    var jns_srt = $("#i_dok").val();

    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: true
    }, function () { 
        //I don't know what to write here. 
        });
});

 <form name="frm_input" id="frm_input_srt" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('Admin/rekam_srt_msk'); ?>">
<table>
 <tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; padding:0; vertical-align:middle"><input type="text" name="test" /></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center; padding:0; vertical-align:middle">
                    <input type="reset" id="btn_reset" name="btn_reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset">
                    &nbsp;||&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" name="btn_submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows how to run different code on cancel and confirm. Straight from their [site](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/):

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
  }
});
```

For your code:

```
$("#frm_input_srt").submit( function () {
    var jns_srt = $("#i_dok").val();

    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: true
    }, function(isConfirm){
      if (isConfirm) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's still not stop on confirmation window. My form is sent without confirmation when I click button

Comment: I've edit it. The form is simplified (my actual form is complicated)

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Is there any js code that could be conflict/override this code? Or any console.log errors?

Answer (score 0):

you can get your form element by Id then submit.

```
document.getElementById("frm_input_srt").submit();
```

or jquery way

```
$("#frm_input_srt").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 }, function () { 
 //to submit:
 document.getElementById("frm_input_srt").submit();
 });
```

Comment: It's still being sent without I am clicking yes

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#btn_submit").on('click',function(e){ //also can use on submit
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit
    var jns_srt = $("#i_dok").val();

    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: true
    }, function (getAction) { 
if (getAction.value === 'true') {
        // Insert code that will be run when user clicks Ok.
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer

```
("#btn_submit").on('click',function(e){ //also can use on submit
e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    closeOnConfirm: true
}
}).then(function(value) {
    if (value) {
      $('#frm_input_srt').submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD: 2021

```js
$("#frm_input_srt")
.submit(async () => {
    const jns_srt = $("#i_dok").val();

    const result = await swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: true
    });
    
    if(!result.isConfirmed)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```